# Open a Vaadin `TabSheet` tab into a separate window

Tags: tabs, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to give my users the option of opening a tab into its own window rather than merely switching the current window’s display to that tab. I have lots of tabs in my app, and the user often wants to study a few of those over long periods of time. For example, the user may watch charts being updated over time via Push.

Currently I add an "Open Window" button to a tab's layout. This opens a new browser window with the current tab’s layout.

Is there any other way to do this? A context-menu on the tab itself? User holding down a keyboard modifier (Control key, Command key, Option/Alt key) while clicking the tab?

Comment: No, open window is the only way to open a new window

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is one trick:

```
tabSheet.setCloseHandler((tabsheet, tabContent) -> {/** make new window **/});
```

Of course it works if `tabSheet` is `closeable`.
So if anybody click close button then you could do your own logic - in this example open new window.

But it could be misleading. To handle this problem you could replace close caption from `x` to any other more meaningful sign.

For example, look at [Valo TabSheet demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!tabs). If you look in HTML code, than you notice something like this:

```
<span class="v-tabsheet-caption-close" aria-hidden="true" aria-disabled="true">×</span>
```

I think you are able to change this `x` using for example JavaScript.